# Flow Hitting Governor's Limits

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow that I have been working on for a month now.  I got it to work in my Salesforce Sandbox, but I can't get it to run in Production.  It keeps hitting the Governor's Limits.  I contacted Salesforce Support, but they told me that they cannot assist with the structure of my flow.  Below is a snapshot of my flow.  Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong or a way to improve what I have?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the Flow equivalent of a "query in a loop." I don't think there's a way to fix this, as Flows don't really handle this type of logic well. What you need is a way to write a "Map", as we'd call it in Apex, and there's no Flow version of a map. That fast lookup would ideally be placed with a way to query all the records at once, then look them up from the saved collection.

Comment: Agree, dont see a way to really do this more efficiently with flow.  If this is running as a screen flow, then you can strategically pop a screen element to reset your transaction limits.